# Implement std::convert::From on type from another crate

Tags: rust

I have an external `geometry` crate that defines a rectangle struct made of floats and an external `sdl2` crate that defines a rectangle struct made of integers.

The following code is how I would expect to convert a `geometry::Rect` to an `sdl2::SdlRect` using the `std::convert::From` trait:

```
extern crate geometry;
extern crate sdl2;

fn main() {
    let geo_rect = geometry::Rect::default();
    let sdl_rect = sdl2::SdlRect::from(geo_rect);
}

impl From<geometry::Rect> for sdl2::SdlRect {
    fn from (rect: geometry::Rect) -> sdl2::SdlRect {
        sdl2::SdlRect {
            x: rect.x as i32,
            y: rect.y as i32,
            w: rect.w as i32,
            h: rect.h as i32,
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile because either the trait I'm implementing or the struct it's being implemented for must come from the current crate. The only solution I've found that works is to define a `MyFrom` trait that mirrors the functionality of the `std::convert::From` trait:

```
extern crate geometry;
extern crate sdl2;

fn main() {
    let geo_rect = geometry::Rect::default();
    let sdl_rect = sdl2::SdlRect::my_from(geo_rect);
}

pub trait MyFrom<T> {
    fn my_from(T) -> Self;
}

impl MyFrom<geometry::Rect> for sdl2::SdlRect {
    fn my_from (rect: geometry::Rect) -> sdl2::SdlRect {
        sdl2::SdlRect {
            x: rect.x as i32,
            y: rect.y as i32,
            w: rect.w as i32,
            h: rect.h as i32,
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not particularly happy with this solution because knowing when to call `my_from` instead of `from` will get confusing down the line. Is there another way for me to solve this using more idiomatic Rust?

Answer (score 3):

Better define your own rectangle type that wraps an externally defined rectangle, and use the standard `From` trait.

This is one possible use of the [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) pattern.

Comment: The newtype pattern seems unfinished in current Rust--while there are a few crates that attempt to get around its limitations, but as it stands it was a hassle to try and implement and didn't make the code any simpler. What I ended up doing was changing the `my_from` method to `from_sdl`. Naming the method `from_sdl` is in line with the standard library's `CStr::from_bytes` method.

Comment: Why not `impl Into<other_crate::Type> for my_crate::Type` instead of newtype, if you only need to perform that one way conversion?

Comment: link seems to be broken